# Auto threshold functionality in a gimp script-fu

Tags: gimp, script-fu

In the GIMP UI, there is an Apply Threshold functionality (GIMP 2.6) which has an option called Auto. This automatically calculates an appropriate lower threshold value for the image. Is this function/option available to use in a plugin? The gimp-threshold and gimp-histogram functions don't seem to have this option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution I finally used. Works only for grayscale images. Its the same algorithm as in the gimp_histogram_get_threshold function in gimphistogram.c

http://git.gnome.org/browse/gimp/tree/app/base/gimphistogram.c

```
(define (auto-threshold imagePath)
    (let*
        (
            (theImage (car (gimp-file-load
                                    RUN-NONINTERACTIVE
                                    imagePath
                                    imagePath
                            )
                    )
            )

            (theDrawable (car  (gimp-image-get-active-drawable theImage)))
            (hist (get-hist theDrawable 0))
        )
        (get-auto-threshold hist)
    )
)

;returns the threshold 
(define (get-auto-threshold hist)
    (let*
        (
            (hist_max (vector-ref hist 0))
            (chist (make-vector 256))
            (cmom (make-vector 256))
            (maxval 255) ;end - start
            (i 1)
            (tmp )
            (chist_max)
            (cmom_max)
            (bvar_max 0)
            (threshold 127)
        )

        (vector-set! chist 0 (vector-ref hist 0))
        (vector-set! cmom 0 0)

        (set! i 1)
        (while (<= i maxval)
            (if (> (vector-ref hist i) hist_max)
                (set! hist_max (vector-ref hist i))
            )
            (vector-set! chist i (+ (vector-ref chist (- i 1)) (vector-ref hist i)) )
            (vector-set! cmom i (+ (vector-ref cmom (- i 1)) (* i (vector-ref hist i))) )
            (set! i (+ i 1))
        )

        (set! chist_max (vector-ref chist maxval))
        (set! cmom_max (vector-ref cmom maxval))

        (set! i 0)      
        (while (< i maxval)
        (if (and (> (vector-ref chist i) 0) (< (vector-ref chist i) chist_max) ) 
            (let* 
               ((bvar (/ (vector-ref cmom i) (vector-ref chist i))))

               (set! bvar (- bvar (/ (- cmom_max (vector-ref cmom i)) (- chist_max (vector-ref chist i)) ) ))
               (set! bvar (* bvar bvar))
               (set! bvar (* bvar (vector-ref chist i)) )
               (set! bvar (* bvar (- chist_max (vector-ref chist i)) ))

               (if (> bvar bvar_max) 
                  (begin
                    (set! threshold i)
                    (set! bvar_max bvar)
                  )
                )

            )   
        )
        (set! i (+ i 1))
    )

    threshold
)   


)

;returns the raw histogram  with values 0-1 as an array
(define (get-hist drawable chan)
(let* (
(i 0)
(hist (make-vector 256))
)
(set! i 0)
(while (< i 256)
(vector-set! hist i (car (cddddr (gimp-histogram drawable chan i i))))
(set! i (+ i 1))
)
hist
)
)
```

Comment: just what I was looking for, thanks. I had to change the chan param of  get-hist to 5 which is GIMP_HISTOGRAM_RGB to get it to match the value as called from the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as of GIMP version 2.6, this feature is not exposed to the Procedural Database (API) ,and thus can't be used in a script-fu or Python script.

Comment: Yes I came to the same conclusion. But I searched the GIMP source code and came across this function gimp_histogram_get_threshold in gimphistogram.c which seems to do all that magic. I'm trying to convert that algorithm into script-fu. However, unfamiliarity with Scheme is slowing me down. Will try and post a solution to this as soon as possible.

Comment: I looked for this function recently and decided against trying to implement it in script-fu.  I left it to the user to copy the value the Auto button calculates from the threshold dialog into my script's parameter dialog, sigh.  If you come up with usable code, I'm sure I'm not the only one who could make use of it.  Optimal thresholding is a basic image manipulation technique.

Comment: @aldrin: I actually had in the past added some missing entries to the PDB - thank you for your research - it may be stil l in time to get it in GIMP 2.8 (which should be out in a few weeks)

Comment: @jsbueno awesome! that would be nice to have.